# How do I prevent iphone from resizing fonts of my website

Tags: iphone, css

Iphone changes some fonts making the site unproportional and not as originally designed. Is there a way to preserve original?

Comment: I would like to humbly request that we not refer to "iphone" in the 3rd person, as if it were a sentient being. ;)

Comment: i fogot my meds today. they usually know how to control me.

Comment: Whenever I hear that third-person-iphone thing I can't help but remember the iRack http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rw2nkoGLhrE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
html, body, form, fieldset, p, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}
```

Source: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-useful-code-snippets-to-develop-iphone-friendly-websites
(you can find many other nice tips for iPhone specific coding there as well)